# Why do we divide by the squared norm of a vector (and not just its norm) when calculating the normal curvature along a direction?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm following a course on Discrete Differential Geometry using the following notes: [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/DDG/paper.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ekmcrane/Projects/DDG/paper.pdf)

On page 37, the author states that the change in normal along a direction for a curve is given (by Frenet-Serret) as $dN = \kappa T - \tau B$. Then he states that "we can get the normal curvature along $X$ by extracting the tangential part of $dN$":

$$\kappa_n(X) = \frac {df(X) \cdot dN(X)}{|df(X)|^2}$$

I'm struggling to understand why this is the case. From my understanding, the tangent vector in the direction of $X$, T, should be $T = \frac {df(X)}{|df(X)|}$. So to retrieve the curvature we multiply both sides of the $dN$ expression given by Frenet-Serret by T to get $dN \cdot T = (\kappa T - \tau B) \cdot T$ which then becomes

$$dN(X) \cdot \frac {df(X)}{|df(X)|} = \kappa$$

Since $T \cdot T = 1$ and $T \perp B$.

What am I getting wrong? Why am I missing a norm in the denominator?

Comment: First, the equation $dN = \dots$ is incorrect. It needs to be $dN(X) = \dots$, where $X = T$ is the unit tangent vector to the curve. This is very sloppily written. $dN$ as it stands is not a vector.

Comment: @TedShifrin can you elaborate on that?

Comment: The sign on $\kappa$ is also wrong, according to every differential geometry treatment I know. I do not know why Crane chooses to do this. Look at his earlier discussion of Frenet for why you need $|dT(X)|=\kappa$, etc. I would suggest that you look at more standard treatments of curves and surfaces (not in the discrete setting), such as my own (linked in my profile), but that may end up confusing you more.